# How to use the heroku environment variable in a maven application to bind http server

Tags: java, maven, heroku, environment-variables, webapp-runner

do you know where do I need to put the heroku http port in my web app?

The only documentation I can find is: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications  but I do not use eighter of those options which are in the documentation. I can't find no java maven web application example. The only examples I can find are for node.js.

I deploy my app just by using:

```
heroku war:deploy warfile.war --app myproject
```

Comment: What kind of application it is? SpringBoot application? JaxWS WSDL endpoint? JEE web application?

Comment: It is really hard to guess what you really need from the description provided. Maven can read environment variables as described here https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html

Comment: @Nikolas it is a maven jax-rs web application

Comment: @MarcinKrasowski I need to find out how to set the port number (which is provided by heroku) in my webapplication. thanks I will look this up

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of two solutions:

**1)** At the webpage of Heroku Dev Centre describing the [Configuring WAR Deployment with the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt), you find the [Configuring Tomcat Options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt#configuring-tomcat-options) which describes commands configuring the way a war file will be executed on the server by setting the `WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS` configuration variable on your application with a wide range of options described at [Webapp Runner: Options](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner#options). You might find the `--port` interesting that is set to `8080` by default and can be configured like:

```
heroku config:set WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS="--port=9090"
```

**2)** Another solution is at Heroku Dev Centre [Create a Java Web Application Using Embedded Tomcat](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat).

Basically, it means that the application will be launched on the embedded Tomcat using dependencies. This provides an ability to configure the Tomcat directly at the code-base of your project.

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf("9090"))

// defining context and localizing resources

tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
```